# Is there a way to avoid using BigIntegers when conducting incredible big numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, biginteger

I was trying to code a program which could get input about a fibonacci number from user and use that number to get the index of that fibonacci number.

So I searched online about fibonacci number and I only find one usable formula, which is `a(n) = [ Phi*n - (phi)*n ]/Sqrt[5]`. n is the index of fibonacci number and a(n) is the number. Therefore I used this formula to make a program as below:

```
/** Fibonacci Sequence
  * Tony
  */
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.*;
public class Solution67 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int times = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
//    String fNumstr = sc.next();
//    BigInteger fNum = new BigInteger(fNumstr);
      int fNum = sc.nextInt();
      double pPhi = (1 + Math.sqrt(5))/2;
      double pphi = (1 - Math.sqrt(5))/2;
      int n = 0;
      while ((int)(Math.pow(pPhi, n) - Math.pow(pphi, n)) != (int)(fNum * Math.sqrt(5))) 
        //^ how to make Math.pow(pPhi, n) a big Integer
      {
        n ++;
      }
      System.out.print(n + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

So it worked fine with small numbers. However if I use a incredibly big number like `86168291600238450732788312165664788095941068326060883324529903470149056115823592713458328176574447204501` Then it gives me an error message and I know why. So I thought maybe I should use BigInteger and BigDecimal instead of int and double to solve this problem. But somehow I feel my method of making this program seems a little bit too complicated and inefficient. Because I have to let my computer try all the number from 0 to the actual index and I can hardly use BigInteger and BigDecimal without generating inaccurate number and fail this thing. So I might want to ask if there is a better way to do this thing at the beginning or my way is the only way and I just have to use BigInteger and BigDecimal? Thx!

Hello so I viewed all the answer and response here. Some I don't fully understand yet. But I think what I am struggling with is that I feel the way I solve it gets too complicated and I think maybe the way I try to make this program is in completely wrong direction. So I just try to find the most simplest algorithm to do this task.

I probably will still use BigInteger and BigDecimal to solve this question. I was confused before by the accurate of square root but now I think since every value is not that close so I probably can use rounded value and it will probably still work.

@PeterLawrey I don't understand what you mean by `If you are calculating every number adding the two previous numbers is the fastest, most accurate and simplest way to do it.` but I got a feeling it seems to be some interesting simple way to make this work. Could you explain it to me, please?

So I finished my code using a recursion function getFN to get Fibonacci number f(n) from parameter n. The code is as below:

```
/** Fibonacci Sequence
  * Tony
  */
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.*;
public class Solution67 {
  public static BigInteger getFN (int n) {
    BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0");
    if (n == 1) {
      return zero;
    }
    else if (n == 2) {
      return one;
    }

    else {
      BigInteger fn = getFN(n-1).add(getFN(n-2));
      return fn;
    }
  }



  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int times = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      String fNumstr = sc.next();
      BigInteger fNum = new BigInteger(fNumstr);
      int n = 1;
      while (!fNum.equals(getFN(n))) {
        n ++;
      }
      System.out.print(n-1 + " ");


    }
  }
}
```

and it works but as I predicted this violent way(try every n until get the right n) is very inefficient. When I run this program with very big numbers it just keeps processing. (I am sure this program works because I tried it with small number. )

Comment: You know how 1 byte is 8 bits, and can represent 256 distinct values (including 0)? You could create (manage resizing) a large array and treat it like bits: every time some number is added to it, you add the bits, minding to "carry the 1", all the way up from 0 to highestUsedBit ..slightly more involved, but you get the gist. I assume one of those classes you mentioned does that for you?

Comment: " I can hardly use BigInteger and BigDecimal without generating inaccurate number and fail this thing" ? You use BigInteger/BigDecimal to *accurately* represent big numbers. Otherwise you can use `double` which can represent very big numbers, but not accurately.

Comment: There is a better way of calculating Fibonacci numbers. Why don't you use  the straightforward `F[n]=F[n-1]+F[n-2]` formula (though this will require sing BigIntegers too)?

Comment: There is a problem with a formula based on using Math.sqrt(). This is only defined for doubles so will not help you if you require more precision. You could, of course, use some other algorithm to find the square root to a higher precision. But then that algorithm is likely to be trickier than finding the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: This isn't quite a complete answer, but: `|pphi|<1`, so `pphi**n` goes to zero very rapidly.  This means that `fNum` is essentially `Pphi**n/√5`, so that `n` is approximately `log(fNum*√5)/log(Pphi)`.  The question now is how to make that accurate enough to be useful, but this will prevent you from needing to calculate everything up to `n`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Oh I thought BigDecimal can't represent infinite repeated decimal numbers. Now I think maybe I can set their scale and it still can work.

Comment: @Leon Do you mean I use that formula to generate all the numbers into an array and then I use indexOf to get the index?

Comment: @Salixalba yes that's what I am confused before. But now I thought maybe I don't need very precision because I can use rounded number as condition too as long as it is not very close number.

Comment: @Salixalba: My implementations of `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` (in Object Pascal/Delphi) do have a `sqrt()` function, and it is not very tricky at all. It uses a simple Newton-Raphson implementation, and works remarkably well. My types even have an `nthRoot()` that works equally well, and is not much more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using BigInteger by using Strings or StringBuilder instead.  This is not as crazy as it sounds as BigInteger.toString is pretty expensive for large numbers and add is fairly easy to implement.

---

If you are calculating every number adding the two previous numbers is the fastest, most accurate and simplest way to do it. You can use BigInteger for large values.

Note: the most expensive part is printing the number which is O(n^2) or better with some smarts, where n is the number of digits.

You can use BigDecimal with this formula but this only make sense if you want to pick a large value at random or want a fractional fibonacci value.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the O(n log n) claim? Simple base conversion is an O(n^2) algorithm. That can certainly be improved by using fancy algorithms (mostly just using a fast multiplication algorithm), but O(n log n) seems a stretch.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Good point big-O is meant to be an upper bound but I used it as a lower bound.

Comment: I was curious, so I looked up the [source](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/math/BigInteger-source.html) (though I'm not sure whether this is the right place to be looking for the actual source). Looking at around line 1510, it looks as though it's simply doing the obvious quadratic-time thing (divide by 10 to get a digit, add that digit to the output, repeat).